# I'm forced to call a controller method from a view, how do I refactor my code?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, model, controller

Okay so, I'm working with CodeIgniter. `posts.php` is my view that displays all the posts, *each post must display its corresponding comments*, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a method in my model that takes the postid(`$postid`) and return its corresponding comment(`$comment`), unless I call the model method via a controller method,how do I accompolish this?

This is my view :

```
<body>
    <?php foreach ($post as $key):?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="span10">

        <div id="box" class="alert-message block-message info">
            <div id="post" class="post">
                <?php echo $key->content;?><br />
            </div>
            <div>
            <p><?php //echo $comment;?></p> <!--HERE THE COMMENTS OF THE CORRESPONDNING POST MUST BE ECHOED-->
            </div>
            <div>
            <a href="#" id="commentnow<?php echo $key->postid;?>"><p><em>Comment</em></p></a>
            </div>
            <div id="commentarea<?php echo $key->postid;?>">
            <?php $name=array('name'=>"form$key->postid");
                  echo form_open("/welcome/comments/$key->postid",$name);
                  $data=array(
                                'id' => 'input',
                                'name'=> 'content',
                                'rows' => '2',
                                'placeholder' => "Write a comment...",
                                'autofocus' => 'TRUE'             
                      );
                  echo form_textarea($data);    

            ?>
            <a href="JAVASCRIPT:form<?=$key->postid;?>.submit()" id="cbtn" class="btn primary small">Comment</a>
            <?=form_close();?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $("div#commentarea<?=$key->postid;?>").hide(); 
    $('a#commentnow<?=$key->postid;?>').click(function(){

        $("div#commentarea<?=$key->postid;?>").slideToggle(250);
        }); 
    });

    </script>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </body>
```

This is my controller method that returns the comments that corresponds to the postid:

```
public function comments($postid)
{

    //Post Comment
    $comment=$this->input->post('content');
    $data=array('content'=>$comment,'comment_postid'=>$postid);
    $this->comments->postcomment($data);

    //Retrieve
    $comments['comment']=$this->comments->retrieve($postid);
    $this->load->view('posts',$comments);

}
```

I'm a newbie,pardon me if my code is bad. I'm always looking forward to improving my code> Thanks for being patient. :)

Comment: ? you pass them to the view as you pass the posts, don't see the problem. Please be clearer and specify exactly what's the issue

Comment: I'm sorry. I've edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: To answer your headline question. It's impossible to call a controller from a view in CI. It's just not built to work that way. Like @DamienPirsy said, load the comments in your controller and pass them to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems to me that you haven't fully understood how to use the MVC.

Firstly, your controller method *comments* contains the extraction of comments **AND** adding comments to a post. This doesn't seem logical when taking a look at the view file.

Instead you should seperate those two.

In your controller, add another metod called *post_comment* and move the adding comment functionality to that method and add a redirection afterwards:

```
public function post_comment($postid)
{

    //Post Comment
    $comment=$this->input->post('content');
    $data=array('content'=>$comment,'comment_postid'=>$postid);
    $this->comments->postcomment($data);

    redirect('welcome/comments'); //redirect back to comments
}
```

Now, remove the adding of a comment from your *comment* method in the controller, so that you only retrieve the comments:

```
public function comments($postid)
{

    //Retrieve
    $comments['comment']=$this->comments->retrieve($postid);
    $this->load->view('posts',$comments);
}
```

And finally change your view file - you need to post the comment to a new URL:

```
        <?php $name=array('name'=>"form$key->postid");
              echo form_open("/welcome/post_comment/$key->postid",$name);
```

This should do the trick.